# How does BIOS (generally) change settings on the processor?

Tags: assembly, x86, processor, bios, amd-processor

I want to confirm my understanding of how BIOS (generally) works such that I can emulate some of the actions it takes without using the kernel driver / userspace library. My goals are purely academic otherwise I would use one of the aforementioned.

Reading through [AMD's documentation](https://github.com/amd/amd_hsmp) it looks like there are three mechanisms two change processor settings:

1. Host System Management Port (HSMP)
2. Epyc System Management Interface (E-SMI) - This is really just a userspace library that is calling into the kernel HSMP driver
3. Run commands directly on the processor

I know the BIOS isn't doing 1 or 2 so I assume that it is doing option 3? Is that correct? From reading through the [Processor Programming Reference](https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/55898_B1_pub_0.50.zip) volume 1 I'm trying to figure out how the BIOS sets things. For example taking a look at a Dell R7525's BIOS and looking at the L2 cache controls (sorry about the foreign language - working on my Mandarin):

[image]

I cross referenced that with page 168 of the PPR vol 1 and it appears to match this instruction:

[image]

I assume that if I wanted to disable the L2 Stream HW Prefetecher option what the BIOS is (likely) doing is that on boot it is issuing a [wrmsr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/wrmsr--write-msr-) (write Model Specific Register) command with bit 3 set to 1? Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: Bits `63:6` are bits 6 through 63, inclusive. Bits 0 through 5 have been individually defined below. (i.e., there are 64 bits total, starting from bit 0)

Comment: `3 set to 1` -- it's more of a `rdmsr`, `or mask`, `wrmsr` but sure. So it's a 64 bit register, it has bits 63 to 0 (mask values would be the respective power of two). bits 63 to 6 are reserved and you should not touch them.

Comment: Ohhhh thanks @teapot418 that's obvious to me now. I didn't even notice it said reserved next to it ‍♂️. Bits 0-5 are the ones that matter... duh. Sorry I was reading that as 63+6 and I knew it was 64 bits wide so I was like wat. I'm just gonna take that out of the question. I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

The example you show is relatively harmless.  At best you will observe better performance; at worst, worse performance.  It doesn't really affect how the hardware or interfaces are configured.

That isn't true of all settings.   Some settings may require corresponding changes to a system peripheral or bus controller.   That is why these tend to aggregate in the BIOS, since it is specific to both the CPU and board, so can better manage the configuration.